# How to change fragment content in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, firebase-realtime-database

## What I would like to achieve:

I have a flow where a user can choose among groups/categories of items (first tab) and see the list of items (in the second tab) and do other things in the third tab (not important here)

When the user lands on the application the first time the default group/category is chosen (in the first tab) and the corresponding list of items is displayed (in the second tab)

[image]

**When the user selects a different group (in the first tab) I would like to change the list (in the second tab).**

so the main question is:

**What is the best and correct way to achieve this?**

## My current Implementation:

**UI: Swipe Views with Tabs**

I've choosen a layout with tabs and swipe view. Each tab is a different fragment declared in a FragmentPageAdapter. Everything contained in a ViewPager as explained in tutorial at https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

**Backend: Firebase**

Each fragment takes data from Firebase DB as list of objects through a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

### Trying different solutions... What do you think is the best approach?

**1. Use a different Layout?**

Implement the user flow in a different way without swipe views

*For example, It could be a floating button to first choose a group of items and then see them in another activity, but in this way coming back to groups/categories is not easy as with swipe views.*

**2. Dinamycally Change Fragment in TAB2?**

When the user select a group in TAB1 create a new fragment initalised with a different DatabaseReference and change it in TAB2 through FragmentManager.

*I've read many posts here on StackOverflow about dinamically changing
fragment in ViewPager but I didn't find really a definitive way to do  it. (nested fragments? holder fragment for viewpager?...)*

**3. Change the Firebase backend reference only?**

The idea is to change the Firebase DatabaseReference used to initialise the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter so that a new list of items is loaded, using the same fragment declared in FragmentPageAdapter.

*I still didn't find a solution on how to do this*

Before speaking of implementations... any idea about the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I will use `EventBus` or `RxJava`.Another implemention is :

#### STEP1:

Send chosen data in your first tab to `Activity`.

#### STEP2:

Send data to second tab from `Activity`

#### STEP3:

In second `fragment`, you can use load data from database in `onCreateView`

#### STEP4:

If your second fragment uses single pattern,you can call `adapter.setList(yourList)` and `adapter.notifyDataChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Solution I found**

I used the approach to change the Firebase Adapter using the same fragment already declared in ViewPager and it works fine.

I post here below my code if someone has the same scenario and want to implement in the same way.

In the FyrebaseRecyclerAdapter of the first Fragment (first tab), in populate view method you just create a new Firebase Database Reference and create a new adapter to set in the recyclerview.

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String groupKey = getRef(position).getKey();

        // Getting the RecyclerView used by Second Fragment (Second TAB)
            RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)fragmentContainer.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.second_recycler_view);

            FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference dbRef = db.getReference("Groups").child(groupKey)

            // Set the new adapter so that fragment 2 update data
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Member, MemberViewHolder> mAdapter = new MyAdapter(Member.class, R.layout.member, MemberViewHolder.class, dbRef);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```